# Limit of ratio between convex and concave function

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I have a question regarding a function of one variable defined on $\mathbb{R}_+$ and differenciable.

It's true the following result: if you have a convex function $f(x)$ and a concave function $g(x)$, then:
$$\lim_{x \to + \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = + \infty?$$
In other words, $f(x)$ being convex grows more rapidly than a concave one?
How can I prove this? Any ideia?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=-x^4$.

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}-\frac{1}{x^2}=0
$$

Answer (score 0):

Even if you consider two functions such that
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x) = \lim_{x\to +\infty} g(x) = +\infty$$
the assertion is false. Consider, e.g.
$$f(x) = x+\frac1x$$
(convex) and
$$g(x) = x-\frac1x$$
(concave). In this case you have
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1.$$